# Any hint to show this flow property?

Tags: differential-geometry

I just wonder if someone might help with this exercise.

Let $X$ be a vector field on a compact smooth manifold $M$ and let $\phi_t$ be the flow of $X$. Show that for all $x \in M$, then

\begin{align} \phi_{t+s}=\phi_t(\phi_s(x))\end{align}

Thanks so much.

Comment: Hint: Note that the map $\Phi_t$ is defined by ODE. Such a solution has uniqueness property.